# Track SVN repository in a Git branch

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

We use Git exclusively for our project, but we now are sharing the project code with another team. They grabbed the raw code from our development branch and setup an SVN repository with it. They cannot use Git and they won't be contributing much to development. But, they are requiring us to push updates back to their SVN repository.

**Caveat**: They have also made some very minor changes to the code to fit their project.

This is my plan:

- Setup a new Git branch called `svn-branch` that tracks their SVN repository
- Use `git cherry-pick` to add commits from our development branch to the new `svn-branch`, and then use `dcommit` to push the changes to the SVN repository.
- They won't be making many commits from their end, but if just in case they do I was thinking I could `cherry-pick` from the `svn-branch` back to our main development branch.

Will this work? If yes, how would I go about setting up a new git branch from within the existing repository to track their SVN repository?

Answer (score 1):

Most simple will be probably to setup a git mirror of their SVN repository in some directory (via git-svn) and then fetch from this repository to your new one.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Would we be able to fetch bi-laterally between the two repositories? Is it not possible to track an SVN repository in a git branch?

Comment: what do you mean "between two repositories" ... if the question is whether git svn can commit to SVN, then the answer is yes (see git-svn(1) and specifically git svn dcommit). For the second question ENOPARSE, sorry ... what do you mean? Just try it and you will see, it is not that complicated.